# Legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm wondering how can I do the following:
I have a `DataFrame` with points and classes. I'd like to draw all points and use one color for each class. How can I specify how classes refer to colors in the legend?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=1600) 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(points1 = data_plot[:,0], points2 = data_plot[:,1], \
             target = target[0:2000]))
colors = {1: 'green', 2:'red', 3:'blue', 4:'yellow', 5:'orange', 6:'pink', \                             
              7:'brown', 8:'black', 9:'white'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['points1'], df['points2'], c = df['target'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))
```

Comment: Can You provide minimal runnable example with the output that You are getting and the output that You would like to get? It would be easier to understand and answer Your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get your legend to have separate entries for each color (and therefore it's `target` value) is to create a separate plot object for *each* `target` value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
target = np.random.randint(1,9, size=100)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(points1=x, points2=y, target=target))
colors = {1: 'green', 2:'red', 3:'blue', 4:'yellow', 5:'orange', 6:'pink', \
              7:'brown', 8:'black', 9:'white'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for k,v in colors.items():
    series = df[df['target'] == k]
    scat = ax.scatter(series['points1'], series['points2'], c=v, label=k)

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: I would not say 'only' way, just the most straight forward ;)  You can do some fun stuff with proxy artists. See http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists